# How to optimize MySQL query with "file sorting" and "using temporary" (it takes more than 10 seconds)

Tags: mysql

I know there's a thousand similar questions, and I read a lot of them, but I don't know how to improve the performance of the following query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(c.date, "%d/%m/%Y") AS ddmmyy, c.idQualification, q.name,
SUM(idContactList = "") + COUNT( DISTINCT NULLIF( CONCAT( c.idContactList, c.idActivity ), "" ) ) AS numCalls

FROM callsBreakdown c
LEFT JOIN qualification q ON q.idQualification = c.idQualification
LEFT JOIN activityCampaign a ON (a.idActivity = c.idActivity)
LEFT JOIN qualificationCampaign qc ON (qc.idCampaign = a.idCampaign AND qc.idQualification = c.idQualification)

WHERE c.date BETWEEN "2011-01-01" AND "2012-10-01"
GROUP BY c.date, q.name
```

If the date range is wide, like 1 year or more, the query takes 10-12 seconds to finish. In the EXPLAIN about callsBreakdown table (the others have "using index" in Extra column and they're quick):

```
id  select_type table type  possible_keys   key     key_len ref   rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE       c     ALL  date           NULL     NULL  NULL  379553  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

The server doesn't use date index and need temporary table and filesort. Any idea? Thanks!

*Edit: I change the alias "date" to "ddmmyy" and the result is the same. Alias is not the problem.*

*Edit 2: If the date range is two months or less, MySQL use date index (key) instead "NULL" key*

Comment: An index is not guaranteed to be used. MySQL has a cost based optimizer. If it considers that the cost of using the index is greater than the cost of not using it, then it won't use it.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `GROUP BY date`  it uses the alias, which is the output of a function call here:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(c.date, "%d/%m/%Y") AS date, ...
```

Try instead to group by the column in the original table, which should allow the ORDER BY to use an index:

```
GROUP BY c.date, q.name
```

Comment: What about `date` in WHERE? Isn't this also an alias?

Comment: The alias is not the problem, I change it and the result is the same.

Comment: @Stokres: There may be more than one problem.